# delta-io/delta project compile failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, delta-lake

The project is [delta](https://github.com/delta-io/delta).

I've already installed sbt-1.2.8 on my Mac. However, I can't compile this project by using "build/sbt compile". After I type the command and the error is below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.xsbt$boot$Pre$$classMissing$1(Pre.scala:66)
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$$anonfun$getMissing$1.apply(Pre.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.RelativeUrlResolver.filter(RelativeUrlResolver.java:263)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:105)
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.getMissing$d83f809$3a8a6f87(Pre.scala:67)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.checkLoader$2accd70c(Launch.scala:185)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$provider$1(Launch.scala:249)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0$2.apply(Launch.scala:252)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0$2.apply(Launch.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:170)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getScalaProvider0(Launch.scala:251)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$3.call(Launch.scala:240)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScalaProvider(Launch.scala:240)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$1.apply(Launch.scala:141)
    at xsbt.boot.Cache.newEntry(Cache.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Cache.apply(Cache.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:144)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.getScala(Launch.scala:143)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.xsbt$boot$Launch$$getAppProvider0(Launch.scala:219)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anon$2.call(Launch.scala:196)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.internal.Trees
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 69 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Trees
```

I'm a newbie to sbt tools. I've tried to change the sbt version in project/build.properties, but it didn't work. Anyone can help me figure this out?

Comment: Try wiping out ~/.sbt/boot/

Comment: @MedAli I tried but it didn't work. And the boot directory appears again after I execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to compile the project with sbt version 0.13.18 on my mac.